# how to count all files in a couple of folders together

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In a directory called `articles` i have some `.txt` files in it and some subdirectories, which represent a year (like `2020`, `2019`, `2018`  and so on...)

The structure looks like this:

```
articles
   |-> 2020
        |-> 1.txt
            2.txt
            3.txt
   |-> 2019
        |-> 1.txt
            2.txt
            3.txt
   |-> 2018
        |-> 1.txt
            2.txt
            3.txt
   |-> main1.txt
       main2.txt
       main3.txt
```

How can i get the number of all txt files which are in the subdirectories (2020, 2019, 2018 ...)

I already have this:

```
$archive_years = array_filter(glob('articles/*'), 'is_dir'); // read dir only
foreach($archive_years as $archive_year) {
    echo count(glob($archive_year.'/*.txt')); // number of txt files form each year
   // how count number of txt files from all years together??
}
```

Comment: (didn't downvote) where is the issue?

Comment: i have now an output like: 20 (for year 2020), 40 for year 2019... and now i need to count together 20 + 40 and....from all years

Comment: Maintain a variable and keep adding count() value to it. I suppose you didn't code this in the first place.

Comment: i did but i dont how to count all the values from all years together...

Comment: A similar example to make it easier for you https://3v4l.org/l47pJ

Comment: Thnx. I didn't know i had to use `+=`

Comment: You can also use `$count = $count + count($data)`. `+=` is just a short hand way of writing.

Comment: FYI check `GLOB_ONLYDIR` for `glob`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<?php
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/your/dir'));
$files = array();

foreach ($rii as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir() || pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != "txt") {
        continue;
    }
    
    if (!isset($files[$file->getPath()])) {
        $files[$file->getPath()] = 0;
    }
    
    $files[$file->getPath()]++;
    
}

var_dump($files);
```

For example, the following output is all the `.cpp` files in my project directory:

```
array(10) {
  ["mypath/src/networking"]=>
  int(2)
  ["mypath/src/thirdpart/rncryptor"]=>
  int(3)
  ["mypath/src/thirdpart/QProgressIndicator"]=>
  int(1)
  ["mypath/src/model"]=>
  int(4)
  ["mypath/src/views"]=>
  int(8)
  ["mypath/src/helper"]=>
  int(5)
  ["mypath/src/helper/deviceclient"]=>
  int(3)
  ["mypath/src/helper/deviceclient/qwe"]=>
  int(6)
  ["mypath/src/helper/view"]=>
  int(1)
  ["mypath/src"]=>
  int(1)
}
```